# Display text / Number in the Input based on selected days and weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to display the amount in the textbox based on the date selected.For weekdays amount is 200 on sundays amount is 500. How can I do it in jquery? Whether it is possible to do?
How can I do it in jquery?

```
<input type="date" name="mass_date" id="txtDate" required="required" class="col-md-12" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="slDay" name="amount"  />
```

Comment: [Everything](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) [is](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) [possible](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getDay`. Add a event listener to to input change then each time the input changes create a new [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and then use the `getDay` function that returns the day number (`0` for Sunday).

Then you can put a conditional statement to change the `form-control` selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtDate").change(function() {
    var selDate = new Date(this.value);
    if (selDate.getDay() == 0) { //If sunday, can change your logic here
      $(".form-control").val(5000);
    } else {
      $(".form-control").val(2000);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="mass_date" id="txtDate" required="required" class="col-md-12" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="slDay" name="amount" />
```

Comment: While this may solves the OP question please add information on how you got this working. Please do not do code dumping. Thanks.

Comment: Added some explanation. Since the OP knew some jQuery, I thought the one comment would do. :)

Comment: One comment is never enough. Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful` : [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Adding just `getDay` is not a direction to the OP question. The question is `how can i do it` adding getDay will not solve the question. Thanks for doing the right thing by adidng extra info as it will help other users on site and they will benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple version

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtDate").change(function() {
    var dow = new Date(this.value).getDay();
    $(".form-control").val(dow === 1 || dow ===6 ? 2000 : 5000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="mass_date" id="txtDate" required="required" class="col-md-12" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="slDay" name="amount"  />
```